# How to delete a row if a values in a column is not NaN

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning

In the given code it displays only the rows without NaN values but i want only the rows with NaN values in a provided column everything has to be removed

```
df1 = df1[pd.notnull(df1['column_name'])]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am correct, you are looking to keep only the NaN values. You can use `pd.isnull()` to check which rows are NaN and then only keep those. Try this:

```
df1 = df1[pd.isnull(df1['column_name'])]
```